# How to deal with functions include complex number

Tags: complex-numbers

If I have a complex number, say $e^{ix}=\cos x+i \sin x$. According to the definition of complex number, we know that the imaginary part of $e^{ix}$ is $\sin x$ and real part is $\cos x$. But if I have a function like 
$$
f=\ln{e^{ix}}=\ln(\cos x+i \sin x)
$$
(I am not sure whether this kind of function is well defined) 
Then what's the real part and imaginary part of $f$? 
I know the real part of  $f=\frac{1}{e^{ix}}$. But in the case above, I  am totally obstacled.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm

Comment: Would you not expect your log to return $ix$?

Comment: @mvw $e^{ix}=cosx+isinx$ is just a notation invented by Euler  and I don't know what is {ix} in this problem.

Comment: $e^{ix}$, with $x\in \mathbb{R}$, is a nice complex number. In polar coordinates on the Gauss plane it has radius $r=1$ and angle $\phi = x$. And it is the complex exponential function, $e^z$ applied to the argument $z = i x$. Now $z=ix$ is the complex number with real part $0$ and imaginary part $x$, thus $x$ times the imaginary unit $i$.

Comment: @user229922: $e^{ix}$ is more than a notation, much like $e^x$ with a real value of $x$ is more than a notation. These are functions which obey pretty much the same laws of algebra as ordinary exponential expressions with a positive integer in the exponent.

Comment: @user229922: $e^{ix}=cosx+isinx$ is not notation; it is a formula which can be proved, using power series for example. As far as $\ln $, if you mean the inverse of $exp$ then $\ln e^{ix} = ix$ by defintion. Now, asserting $\ln $ exists and proving it are two different things. If you think about it you'll see that if you try to invert the exponential you will run into trouble unless you restrict the range.

Comment: I go to the wikipedia page and begin to consider $e^{ix}$ in a different way.  I agree with you guys' ideas that it's more than a notation. And I think I can finish my problem myself. Thanks for the help!